# MySQL group and insert issue

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join

In plain English, I am trying to get average votes from db1, where the votes are of node type 'article' and then insert the average of votes on each article into the 'likes' field of the corresponding rows in db2.news.

Here is what I cam up with:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO db2.news 
(likes)
SELECT ROUND(AVG(v.value)/10)
FROM db1.votes v, db1.node n, db2.news d
WHERE v.id=n.nid AND n.type='article' AND d.id=n.nid
GROUP BY v.id;
```

The query runs with no error, however it creates loads of junk rows in db2 where only like field is filled.

I am struggling with this for hours so appreciate your hints to fix the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is an insert, which inserts the result set of the inner query. But this result set contains only one column, and lots of rows.

Something similar could help for example:

```
create table votetmp
SELECT v.id, ROUND(AVG(v.value)/10) voteavg
FROM db1.votes v, db1.node n, db2.news d
WHERE v.id=n.nid AND n.type='article'
GROUP BY v.id;

update
  db2.news
set
  likes=(select voteavg from votetmp where votetmp.id=news.id)
```

Comment: Your hint let me see the light! Just 'valueavg' in line 2 and 'AND d.id=n.nid' in line 4 are superfluous. Please update the ansewr and I'll accept it. Many thanks.